# How to prevent double prompt for geolocation in iOS app?

Tags: ios, webview

I have a simple native application where I open a url in a uiwebview. That webview needs to get user's location. The problem is that the app asks for location permission first on the behalf of application with alert "<> would like to access your location"
And after you click "OK" it again prompts for alert "<> would like to access your location"

This is not a desired user experience. Also for the application alert, the language is according to the current locale but for website alert, it comes in English though the locale of device is set to French

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, for you as a developer, to influence these privacy dialogs. Since your app wants the location and the website the will have to agree to them both.

Your seconds problem is a bit harder since it might have to with the localization settings of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Make a UIWebview by coding : 
It will automatically take the language. This code worked for me :

```
NSString *strURL = @"http://www.google.com/";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

myWeb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
myWeb.scalesPageToFit = YES;
myWeb.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:myWeb];

[myWeb loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Still the same. The location access alert for site is still in English. :(

Comment: @JuliGupta have you made it via coding...just try my line of code...and see whether it works or not ?

Comment: Yes. I tried it via code but it was still the same. Though I figured it out. Atleast the localization part. The language for the project was selected as English. I changed it to French and then all the alerts were in French.

Comment: Ok...nice...if you want to solve your issue ..contact me @mrsamkitjain@gmail.com...we can have a chat there

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but Samkit Jain' solution didn't worked.

Double prompt for geolocation is compulsory, but for to translate second alert you must internationalize Main.storyboard. It's work for me. My second alert is in French now. (In english before)

[image]

How internationalize: http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, in the end, we used the WebViewGold for iOS app template for it & using that approach our location-based web app worked out of the box without second / repeated dialog in the WKWebView app. :-)